# Mayan Long Count Calendar in VB.NET

Tags: vb.net, calendar, clock

How do I check the Mayan long count date in VB.NET and move it into a string? I've tried checking the distance between today and the thirteenth baktun (December 21 2012) in an integer but then I can't calculate how to change that integer into a string in the Mayan date format (ex 12.12.12.12.12).

Answer (score 0):

Here it is:

http://pastebin.com/AS1qvhs1

This calculates the distance between today and the thirteenth baktun, then divides the sections of the format the maximum plus one, then mods it by the higher tiers maximum plus one